# How to Add text value in Automatically in this conditions?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, conditional-tags

**how to input a text value in this  conditions automatically , when user input  text fields  value  **

**which condition do I apply ? **

code was added :

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? `WC()->cart->add_to_cart()` adds a product to the cart.

Comment: @Abhik hi ,  The admin who sets the Id in the text should be automatically added here in **[ $woocomerce_wookc_text ] =  " This "   **,  I Exactly try to The data entered into the admin text fields must be executed immediately.   which conditions applying in this formating to run ? I have used this snippet to into cmb2 plugin text. https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-item-to-cart-programmatically/    
    15 is the variable Id. But we need to add text fields id. can you please answer it?

Comment: It's better to type code than paste images :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Untested though.

*I don't know how you get `$woocomerce_wookc_text`, but since you mentioned CMB, I am taking you are saving it as product meta data*

```
function wpse405916_add_to_cart( $cart_item_key, $product_id ) {
    
    //Get the woocomerce_wookc_text value.
    $woocomerce_wookc_text = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'woocomerce_wookc_text ', true );
    
    //Check if the value exists
    if ( $woocomerce_wookc_text && !empty($woocomerce_wookc_text) ) {
        //Set the value as integer
        $woocomerce_wookc_text = (int)$woocomerce_wookc_text;
        
        //Add it to cart
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart($woocomerce_wookc_text);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'wpse405916_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
```

This will automatically add the product associated with the id from `$woocomerce_wookc_text` when the main product is added to cart. There are numerous checks should be added.